# Use httplib to check if a URL will return a certain page?

Tags: python, httplib

Im going through several hundred bit.ly links to see if they have been used to shorten a link. If a link has not, it returns [this page](http://bit.ly/1niCdh9).

How can I iterate through a list of links to check which ones do NOT return this page?

I tried using the head method used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page), however that always returned true, of course.

I looked into the head method, but found out that it never returns any data:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
>>> conn.request("HEAD","/index.html")
>>> res = conn.getresponse()
>>> print res.status, res.reason
200 OK
>>> data = res.read()
>>> print len(data)
0
>>> data == ''
True
```

I'm stumped on this, and any help would be great.

Comment: you want to get the content of the page?

Comment: I was hoping that it would be possible to check the link without loading the content of the page, but if thats the only way it can be done then so be it

Comment: check res.status (e.g., 301 is a redirect)

Comment: when you are getting 200 OK, isn't it sufficient for you?

Comment: @Scherf: I've tried your link from the question and it returns 404 for me (404 is *not* redirect, it is "not found").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `bit.ly` returns `404` http code for non-shorten links:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from urlparse import urlsplit

urls = ["http://bit.ly/NKEIV8", "http://bit.ly/1niCdh9"]
for url in urls:
    host, path = urlsplit(url)[1:3]
    conn = HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request("HEAD", path)
    r = conn.getresponse()
    if r.status != 404:
       print("{r.status} {url}".format(**vars()))
```

Unrelated: to speed up the check, you could use multiple threads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from httplib import HTTPConnection
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool # use threads
from urlparse import urlsplit

def getstatus(url):
    try:
        host, path = urlsplit(url)[1:3]
        conn = HTTPConnection(host)
        conn.request("HEAD", path)
        r = conn.getresponse()
    except Exception as e:
        return url, None, str(e) # error
    else:
        return url, r.status, None

p = Pool(20) # use 20 concurrent connections
for url, status, error in p.imap_unordered(getstatus, urls):
    if status != 404:
       print("{status} {url} {error}".format(**vars()))
```

Comment: This works perfectly. The issue I was having is that when I imported the links from file I forgot to remove the newline character, and because of that they all returned 200. Great answer, thanks

Comment: @Scherf: `urls` in the code is already a list of urls (any iterable will do). Do you mean how to read that list from a file: `urls = [line.strip() for line in open('filename') if line.strip()]`

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a simple way to do that:

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request("http://www.python.org/", "GET")
print content
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples