# How to know if a specific page in a website is down (Batch or Python)

Tags: python, batch-file

Okay so we all know their is many tools that tell you if a website is up down or available, but I want to make a tool that check for pages in a website. Example:
Website www.Example.com is up, but does page www.Example.com/test.html exist?

### The program will take a list from a text file to try, the text file will have:

games
cpanel
signup
index
example
join-us

### etc...

My program output should be like (if it is in batch):
Press 1 to start
Starting...
Online pages:
-cpanel
-games
-joinus
etc...
If it can't be done in batch or python, what other languages can it be done through?
Thanks very much :)

Comment: It can be programmed natively in python as well as in lots of other languages or you can use any of the many command line utilities available on the internet *to check specific urls*. The question is either too broad or vague or doesn't belong to stackoverflow.

Comment: I searched A LOT about it in many forums but got nothing. Do you know where I can find w tutorial or sample program like it? thanks @wOxxOm

Comment: Duplicate of [Python script to see if a web page exists without downloading the whole page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page) (it took 5 seconds to google for `python check if page exists`).

Comment: @wOxxOm Well this is a start but read my post again. I want to import them from a text file and give a final result of pages online  :) Thanks anyways :)

Comment: well that doesn't make this question any more valid or suitable for stackoverflow as it still exhibits zero research effort regardless of your claims otherwise.

Comment: @wOxxOm Well if you don't wont to answer, it is no problem, just don't say it isn't suitable...

Comment: I'm just stating the obvious. You can read the rules under Help link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import urllib2

u = 'http://www.google.com/'

pages =  open('pages.txt', 'r').readlines()

for page in pages:
        url = u+page
        try:
                req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                if e.code == 404:
                        print url+" does not exists"
        else:
                print url+" exists"
```

test it using a `pages.txt` file containing something like this:

```
search
page
plus
signin
account
security
lol
about
someotherpage.html
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I am looking for. Just two questions, is this the full program? And can I make it give a full list at the end with just the pages that worked? Thanks again :)

Comment: Yes, it is the full program. Yes, you can do the same by creating a list and writing the urls into a file.

Comment: I am a noob in python and I don't know advanced things. Can you please help me? I googled but can't get a straight answer. @v1k45

Comment: If it is so, then instead of building the thing directly, learn python basics first. feel free to mark the answer as correct if it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

check [winhttpjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat) - it will set the http response code of a http request to the errorlevel:

```
@echo off
call winhttpjs.bat http://google.com -saveto con >nul
if errorlevel 200 if not errorlevel 300 echo site is available
```

Comment: Well thanks but I said I don't want to check a site I want to check a page in a site (like http://google.com/register )

Comment: @CyberShadow - google.com/register returns 404 for me so the script will  work correctly.With IF conditions you can improve the logic of the examples.