# Python check if website exists

Tags: python, html, urlopen

I wanted to check if a certain website exists, this is what I'm doing:

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent':user_agent }
link = "http://www.abc.com"
req = urllib2.Request(link, headers = headers)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req).read() - ERROR 402 generated here!
```

If the page doesn't exist (error 402, or whatever other errors), what can I do in the `page = ...` line to make sure that the page I'm reading does exit?

Comment: How 'bout an if check to only read if you get 200?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python script to see if a web page exists without downloading the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use HEAD request instead of GET. It will only download the header, but not the content. Then you can check the response status from the headers.

For python 2.7.x, you can use [`httplib`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/library/httplib.html):

```
import httplib
c = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
c.request("HEAD", '')
if c.getresponse().status == 200:
   print('web site exists')
```

or [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2
try:
    urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/some_page')
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print(e.code)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print(e.args)
```

or for 2.7 and 3.x, you can install [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

Comment: Note that `www.abc.com` returns a 301 (Moved) [status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html).

Comment: Can I pass a html link to `.HTTPConnection()` like `http:\\www.abc.com\x\y\z.html`

Comment: @JamesHallen you can use urllib2,

Comment: Note that a HEAD request may fail even though the URL exists. Amazon, for example, returns status 405 (Method Not Allowed) for its front page. An additional GET may be needed in that case.

Comment: This does not work in general.  When I request a page that does not exists I get response code 200 and a page with the following content: `<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http://www.<ORIGINAL_URL>.com/"/></head><body><script>window.location="http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer);</script></body></html>`  I tried this with my vps host and the response is to redirect to gen.xyz.  When scraping webpages I would like to handle this behavior in a dependable way.

Comment: I'm not sure what the old `requests` module is like but now, `requests.head` is the function to use instead of `requests.get`.

Comment: @AdemÖztaş, using `requests` if particular website is not available then it throws `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. There are many other codes than 200 that sites return. Also this does not handle errors that come up going trough long lists of sites.

Comment: @AdemÖztaş Thanks. What about single page applications that are very common in recent years? Do you know any good ways to check if a SPA url exists?

Comment: The requests.get() function returns a response, so naming the variable "response" instead of "request" would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 51):

It's better to check that status code is < 400, like it was done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page). Here is what do status codes mean (taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)):

- `1xx` - informational
- `2xx` - success
- `3xx` - redirection
- `4xx` - client error
- `5xx` - server error

If you want to check if page exists and don't want to download the whole page, you should use [Head Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods):

```
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp = h.request("http://www.google.com", 'HEAD')
assert int(resp[0]['status']) < 400
```

taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421712/771848).

If you want to download the whole page, just make a normal request and check the status code. Example using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://google.com')
assert response.status_code < 400
```

See also similar topics:

- [Python script to see if a web page exists without downloading the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471275/python-script-to-see-if-a-web-page-exists-without-downloading-the-whole-page)
- [Checking whether a link is dead or not using Python without downloading the webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229607/checking-whether-a-link-is-dead-or-not-using-python-without-downloading-the-webp)
- [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)
- [Making HTTP HEAD request with urllib2 from Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421170/python-head-request-with-urllib2)

Comment: I actually did want to download the page, but this was a preliminary step to see if the page existed

Comment: Is there anything wrong with parsing this link: `http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/electricity/caiso-sp15-ez-gen-hub-5-mw-peak-calendar-month-day-ahead-lmp-swap-futures_contract_specifications.html` ?

Comment: The link you've provided has invalid character inside. The correct link is http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/electricity/caiso-sp15-ez-gen-hub-5-mw-peak-calendar-month-day-ahead-lmp-swap-futures_contract_specifications.html. Just replace `http://google.com` with it in my examples and it'll work.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that, please check the answer by `alexce` it works well too.

Answer (score 9):

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, HTTPError, URLError

user_agent = 'Mozilla/20.0.1 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent':user_agent }
link = "http://www.abc.com/"
req = Request(link, headers = headers)
try:
        page_open = urlopen(req)
except HTTPError, e:
        print e.code
except URLError, e:
        print e.reason
else:
        print 'ok'
```

To answer the comment of unutbu:

> Because the default handlers handle redirects (codes in the 300 range), and codes in the 100-299 range indicate success, you will usually only see error codes in the 400-599 range.
>   [Source](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/howto/urllib2.html#error-codes)

Comment: I get this eror: `NameError: global name 'HTTPError' is not defined`

Comment: Did you include the Import, too? I'll have a look at it later, but I tested this Code on my machine

Comment: I figured out my mistake, I had to do: `urllib.HTTPError` (or import like you said). Thanks, it worked well

Answer (score 8):

There is an excellent answer provided by @Adem Öztaş, for use with `httplib` and `urllib2`. For `requests`, if the question is strictly about resource existence, then the answer can be improved upon in the case of large resource existence.

The previous answer for `requests` suggested something like the following:

```
def uri_exists_get(uri: str) -> bool:
    try:
        response = requests.get(uri)
        try:
            response.raise_for_status()
            return True
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
            return False
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False
```

`requests.get` attempts to pull the entire resource at once, so for large media files, the above snippet would attempt to pull the entire media into memory. To solve this, we can stream the response.

```
def uri_exists_stream(uri: str) -> bool:
    try:
        with requests.get(uri, stream=True) as response:
            try:
                response.raise_for_status()
                return True
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
                return False
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False
```

I ran the above snippets with timers attached against two web resources:

1) http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html, a very light html page

2) http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4, a decently sized video file

Timing results below:

```
uri_exists_get("http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html")
# Completed in: 0:00:00.611239

uri_exists_stream("http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html")
# Completed in: 0:00:00.000007

uri_exists_get("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4")
# Completed in: 0:01:12.813224

uri_exists_stream("http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4")
# Completed in: 0:00:00.000007
```

As a last note: this function also works in the case that the resource host doesn't exist. For example `"http://abcdefghblahblah.com/test.mp4"` will return `False`.

Answer (score 7):

I see many answers that use `requests.get`, but I suggest you this solution using only `requests.head` which is faster and also better for the webserver since it doesn't need to send back the body too.

```py
import requests

def check_url_exists(url: str):
    """
    Checks if a url exists
    :param url: url to check
    :return: True if the url exists, false otherwise.
    """
    return requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True).status_code == 200
```

The meta-information contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request should be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request.

Answer (score 5):

**code:**

```
a="http://www.example.com"
try:    
    print urllib.urlopen(a)
except:
    print a+"  site does not exist"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use `stream` method to not download the full file. As in latest Python3 you won't get urllib2. It's best to use proven request method. This simple function will solve your problem.

```py
def uri_exists(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Argument in function is "uri" - should be "url"

Answer (score 4):

```
def isok(mypath):
    try:
        thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(mypath)
    except HTTPError as e:
        return 0
    except URLError as e:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Comment: Consider adding a description with your code; merely posting code does not help the community as it does not help them understand how it works. In order to attract upvotes from the community, consider adding some details of how your code works.

Comment: I think more than one understood my code, but you're right. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

> > > Try this one::

```
import urllib2  
website='https://www.allyourmusic.com'  
try:  
    response = urllib2.urlopen(website)  
    if response.code==200:  
        print("site exists!")  
    else:  
        print("site doesn't exists!")  
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:  
    print(e.code)  
except urllib2.URLError, e:  
    print(e.args)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to check if URL is accessible for POST request but don't want to send any actual data to the API I recommend using the following approach:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.example.com'

try:
    response = requests.options(url)
    if response.ok:   # alternatively you can use response.status_code == 200
         print("Success - API is accessible.")
    else:
        print(f"Failure - API is accessible but sth is not right. Response codde : {response.status_code}")
except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as e:
    print(f"Failure - Unable to establish connection: {e}.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failure - Unknown error occurred: {e}.)
```

Using GET request to check if POST Endpoint exists would result in HTTP 405 – Method Not Allowed, which is a bit problematic, while using `requests.options()` returns HTTP 200.