# Getting Error Path does not exist

Tags: python, remote-access, python-os

In my Code I am checking Remote path

```
if not os.path.exists(dest_dir): 
      print "Dest directory does not exist"
      return
```

But when i access path manually i am able to access.

```
My path is '\\10.223.161.31\D$\images' 

I have set to '\\\\10.223.161.31\\D$\\images'
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.path` only works locally on your machine.

For remote servers, you'd need to do something like here: [Python check if website exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists)

Comment: Before doing that I logging into remote machine using wmi. So it should be accessible path. Then i am copying file from my local machine to remote machine using shutil.copy() –