# Check for valid domain name in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, dns

I am using python and would like a simple regex to check for a domain name's validity. I check at least write domain name.

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow'
        keyword = 'foo'
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            check_keyword(url, keyword)
```

I try unit testing on url textfield and there is main.py page where I done the validation 
main.py-

def check_keyword(url, keyword):

```
if re.match("^(((([A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.)|(([A-Za-z0-9]+(\-)+[A-Za-z0-9]+){1,63}\.))+){1,255}$" ,url):
   return ValueError("Invalid")
```

Example

- www.google (Invalid)
- https://stackoverflow (Invalid)

Comment: you should post your code with what you did / tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python check if website exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Domain name validation with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306690/domain-name-validation-with-regex)

Comment: What is a valid domain name for you? I suggest you to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Answer (score 16):

The [source](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/validators/domain.html#domain) of the [validators module](https://validators.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) shows, that this is maybe a little more complex task.

You could use that module:

```
>>> import validators
>>> validators.domain('example.com')
True

>>> validators.domain('example.com/')
ValidationFailure(func=domain, ...)
```

Or you can use the RFCs for [Domain names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) to construct your own checker.

Comment: I am using that same module and the regular expression that it uses looks weird. Also, it gives this domain as valid: "a.aa*com" and I think it shouldn't be, specially because it has got an asterisk as a part of it.

Comment: validators.domain("example.com") cannot check for subdomains. So, It wiil return True for validators.domain("abc.example.com") also.

Comment: The validators package marks domains with [underscores](https://github.com/kvesteri/validators/issues/102) or [trailing dots](https://github.com/kvesteri/validators/issues/141) as invalid.

Comment: nor can it check for a valid suffix eg. validators.domain('google.notavalidsuffix')   will still return True, but as per PyPI the sub-domain here is 'google', domain='notavalidsuffix' and there is no suffix as per the tldextract. ref: https://pypi.org/project/tldextract/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# Check if a string is a url
    from django.core.validators import URLValidator
    import requests

    try:
        validate = URLValidator()
        validate(url)
        print("String is a valid URL")
    except:
        print("String is not valid URL")
        raise serializers.ValidationError("String is not valid URL")
    
    # Check if the url exists on the internet
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        print("URL is valid and exists on the internet")
    except requests.ConnectionError as exception:
        print("URL does not exist on Internet")
        raise serializers.ValidationError(f'URL {url} does not exist on Internet')
```

**UPDATE :** i found a better solution by using python-whois library
here [valid domain name by whois](https://pyshark.com/get-domain-name-information-using-python/)