# Python differentiate between letters and numbers on input AND loop the task (or get to another location of the file)

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is really frustrating. I'm learning Python right now and can't find a solution for my problem. This is only an example for different outputs. not a code with usage.

here's my Code:

```
text_2 = input("Input number or text: ")

if   text_2 == --number-- :

         print("Your number is: ")

elif text_2 == --text aka string-- :

         print("Your text is: ")

else:
         print("Wrong_Input_1")
```

How can I do, that python recognizes the difference between a number and a string aka letters. my first problem was with

```
if text_2 == str(input) :
      print("Your IP is: ")
```

Python interprets even int's as string

my second problem:
I don't know how Python only takes int as input.
My thought was:

```
if text_2 == int(input) :

      print("Your IP is: ")
```

But that's not working.

the last problem is:

I want something similar to ´goto´.
I know it's different in Python and not recommended to do it. so I need something different. In the following code I will show how it should be like

---

**first_stage**

```
text_2 = input("Which stage will you go?: ")

if   text_2 == "go to second stage" :

         print("going to second stage")
            goto second_stage

elif text_2 == "go to third stage" :

         print("going to third stage")
            goto third_stage


elif text_2 == "go to first stage" :

         print("going to first stage")
            goto first_stage
```

**second_stage**

```
text_3 = input("Which stage will you go?: ")

if   text_3 == "go to first stage" :

         print("going to first stage")
            goto first_stage

elif text_3 == "go to second stage" :

         print("going to second stage")
            goto second_stage


elif text_3 == "go to third stage" :

         print("going to third stage")
            goto third_stage
```

**third_stage**

```
text_4 = input("Which stage will you go?: ")

if   text_4 == "go to third stage" :

         print("going to third stage")
            goto third_stage

elif text_4 == "go to first stage" :

         print("going to first stage")
            goto first_stage


elif text_4 == "go to second stage" :

         print("going to second stage")
            goto second_stage
```

---

Would be nice if you can give me the alternative code for my last problem right in my code.

Last question:
which command do I need to clear the output-window?

Answer (score 0):

To address your second problem, you need to use `a = int(input())` to get an input of type `int` for a. If you would like to keep it as a string, simply use `a = input()` and that will give you an input of type `string` for a. To clear the output window, this question requires more clarity. If you're on a Mac, in your terminal just type `clear`. More information can be found here: https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-Clear-screen-function-in-Python

Comment: The relevant code from that link is `print("\033[H\033[J")`

Comment: Linux ^^

I tried it, too but doesnt work either get an syntax error for this line

Answer (score 0):

Woof. There's a lot to unpack here.

First of all, here's another question about [validating IP addresses in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462784/check-if-a-string-matches-an-ip-address-pattern-in-python).

And here's one about [domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010810/check-for-valid-domain-name-in-a-string).

About the `goto` statements. Most modern languages do not use `goto`. Python is included. Instead they use the following constructs known as control statements.

```
while
if
for
switch (but not in python)
```

Another important construct is known as a [function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp).

That being said, due to this [awesome and weird project](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) you are allowed to completely disregard how the language is intended to be used, and use goto anyway. So there's that.

BTW on mac and maybe linux, you can press CMD-K (CTRL-K) while in a python terminal and it will successfully clear the screen. (In fact it'll clear any command line application).

Comment: It's not actually about IP's and domain.. I didn't found an better example where its important to differentiate between an int input and an str input...

and how do I would use while and for in my code?

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is some information about how to go from using `goto`'s to using "modern" constructs. I'm writing in pseudo code with the exception that control structures will be written in pythonic form.

Control structures are basically shortcuts that replace all the common (and necessary) ways of using goto (jmp) instructions.

### If Statements

```
if notHungry goto skip
Eat
skip:
Sleep
```

Becomes

```
if not notHungry:
    Eat
Sleep
```

Notice how indention is used to define a *code block*. Code blocks remove the need for labels that skip sections of code.

### While Loop

```
c = 0
repeat:
c = c + 1
Say Hello
if c < 100 goto repeat
```

becomes

```
while c < 100:
    c = c + 1
    Say Hello
```

### For Loop

```
c = 0
repeat:
c = c + 1
Say Hello
if Happy goto repeat
Give Cookie
if LateForSchool goto skip
if c < 1000 goto repeat
skip:
```

becomes

```
for c in range(1000):
    Say Hello
    if Happy:
        continue
    Give Cookie
    if LateForSchool:
        break
```

### Functions

Finally, and arguably most importantly is functions.

```
goto skip
doALotOfWork:
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
ret
skip:

Prepare for Work
goto doALotOfWork
Do something else
goto doALotOfWork
```

becomes

```
def doALotOfWork():
    line1
    line2
    line3
    line4
    line5

Prepare for Work
doALotOfWork()
Do something else
doALotOfWork()
```

You can even pass information in and out of functions. (first runnable example)

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

print(square(2))
```

The information flows like this:

```
def square(informationGoingIntoFunction):
    return informationComingBack

print(square(informationGoingIntoFunction))
```

and it prints `informationComingBack`

Comment: But how do I do it, if the code should skip several lines of code? (e.g. 5.000 lines or more)

can you give me the example at my big code with the stages? it's for me way eaysier to understand.

Comment: I don't understand your example. What does it do? @AwesomeSounds

Comment: You can imagine my code as text-adventure..You do an action (input) and then a different text show up. but you have more than one possibility.. so you must be able to get to a totally different line in the code

Comment: I think text adventure is easiest to do using object orientation.. You can have stuff like `stage2 = Stage("this is stage 2");stage1 = Stage("this is stage 1"); stage1.option('go to second stage', stage2)`. Again when it comes to translating from goto to modern paradigm it's really a case by case thing. But it is in fact mathematically provable that you never "need" goto statements.

Comment: I think... ... I don't get it... but let me google "object orientation python"

Comment: OK. Also I made [some code for your example](https://repl.it/@SamyBencherif/Stage-Game-No-GOTO). Hope it helps. Is there anything in particular you are trying to make?

Comment: wow :D its working ^^ and now a cup of coffee and studying the code thanks