# Check if a Website Exists With Requests Isn't Working

Tags: python, web-scraping

So, I learned how Web Scraping works a few days ago and I was messing around today. I wanted to know how I could test if a page exists/doesn't exist. So, I looked it up and I found [Python check if website exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists). I'm using the `requests` `module` and I got this code from the answers:

```
import requests
request = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
if request.status_code == 200:
    print('Web site exists')
else:
    print('Web site does not exist')
```

I tried it out, and since example.com exists, it printed "Web site exists". However, I tried something I was sure wouldn't exist, like examplewwwwwww.com and it gave me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt91l.png). Why is it doing this and how can I keep it from printing out an error (and instead saying that the website does not exist)?

Comment: As that page indicates, it throws a ConnectionError https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists#comment70165050_16778473

Comment: There's no server there to give you a status. Read the comments of that link you posted and instead use something like `try... except ConnectionError`.

Comment: some sites block you thinking this is a scraping attempt, knowing you're not a real browser due to your user agent an other features. This explains why some urls rejected with 404 actually DO work in the browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use try/except like this:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

try:
    request = requests.get('http://www.example.com')
except ConnectionError:
    print('Web site does not exist')
else:
    print('Web site exists')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to list my way of doing it, maybe it can be of value for someone:

```
  try:
     response = requests.get('https://github.com')
     if response.ok:
        ready = 1
        break
  except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
     print("Website not availabe...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you getting the error because the url you want to get is invalid, however you can easily check this with a `try` - `except` block as this one:

```
import requests
from requests.exceptions import MissingSchema

try:
    request = requests.get('examplewwwwwww.com')
except MissingSchema:
    print('The provided URL is invalid.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose `request.get` call with `try/except` and handle various exceptions that might arise, one of which is `ConnectionError`.

You get this because having response `status_code` not equal to 200 and not being able to connect to desired HTTP address are two different things.

[Here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#exceptions) are the exceptions that you might encounter when making requests with `requests` library.