# checking the existence of invalid websites using python

Tags: python, html, httplib2

I have a list of websites and I want to check if they exist .. some of them become invalid recently.

I tried to follow the code provided here: [Python check if website exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778749/3261292),

it works to detect the existence of some sites like:

> http://www.mississippiherald.com
>
> http://www.metropolitanworlds.com
>
> http://www.newsbysquad.com

but for others it doesn't work. It returns the status code (200, as success), but they are not now, like:

> http://www.nbc.com.co/
>
> http://nativeamericans.us/
>
> http://www.nativestuff.us/

is there a way to detect these sites?

I think the problem is because the domain name still exists in the host servers.

Comment: But does a re-direct occur?

Comment: The problem is because even though the domains are available, they are parked and are responding to requests.  I think the next step is to determine if they are parked or not and how you go about that is up to you.  Perhaps you can check to see if you get redirected, that should raise a flag that it *might* be available and do further checks to confirm that.

Comment: The NBC thing appears to have been taken by someone nefarious, or at least it looked that way before I killed the tab. There *is* a site on the other end of that link. It's just probably not the one you wanted to go to.

Comment: @QHarr , no ...