# How "skip" if error inside of a Python function?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, error-handling

I am trying to import tables from multiple pages, and then append each table into one data frame. One of the links does not have a table, which causes the function to not work. Is there a way I can just skip the URLs that result in errors? (There are many more URLs that result in errors that I excluded from this code)

```
import pandas as pd

    
urls = ['https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Stephen-Curry/GameLogs/1600',
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/LeBron-James/GameLogs/250', 
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Anthony-Edwards/GameLogs/117444',
            'https://basketball.realgm.com/player/Jalen-Washington/GameLogs/151233']
    
def fxGameLogs(URL: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    dfs = [] # empty list
    for x in URL:
        GameLog_list = pd.read_html(x)
        GameLogs = GameLog_list[0]
        dfs.append(GameLogs) # append frame to list        
    return pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True) # concat frames and return

GameLogs = fxGameLogs(urls)
print(GameLogs)
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: Would "try", "except", else", or "finally" be used in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a simple if? Or, maybe, use the request function to check for status codes returning before using the site on your for.

Check this out -> [Python check if website exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778435/python-check-if-website-exists)

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of a
link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include relevant content in your answer and leave the link for extra
information or as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The **try** block allows you to test a section of code for faults.
The **except** block allows you to manage errors.

Example:

```
def division(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

division(1, 0)
```

if you run this you will get an error like this>>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
File "<string>", line 2, in division
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

But Using **try...except** Block code can be run without any error

```
def division(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

try:
    division(1, 0)
except:
    pass
```

The best practice is to use specific Error Exception:

```
def division(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

try:
    division(1, 0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

You can also try this:

```
def division(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2

try:
    division(1, 0)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This will print the Error or can be used in Logging.

Comment: I tried playing around with that I think it might work. Is there a way to remove the URL that is causing the error, and then rerun my function?

Comment: I know that certain parts are going to fail, and want to remove them and run it again with the ones that don't fail.