# How do I check if a file on http exists, using Python/django?

Tags: python

How do I check if a file on http exists, using Python/Django?

I try to check if file in http://hostname/directory/file.jpg exist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

```
import urllib2
ret = urllib2.urlopen('http://hostname/directory/file.jpg')
if ret.code == 200:
    print "Exists!"
```

Note that you don't check if *file* exists - you check if *resource* exists

EDIT: The other answer by user *Geo* is better in that HEAD request can be much more efficient as it doesn't fetch resource content.

Answer (score 6):

You could do it with a HEAD request. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python) for more info. If you get a status code of 200, it should be ok, but you could check for content type as well.