# Make client.HTTPConnection connect to a specific IP address

Tags: python, dns, httprequest, ip-address

Is there a way to force Python's `client.HTTPConnection` to connect to a specific IP address? I am writing a program that checks for the presence of a file on a web server, but I want to check every single web server, and the web servers use DNS round-robin. So I am using `dns.resolver.query` to get a list of all of the IP addresses associated with a specific IP address, and then I am using `client.HTTPConnection` to connect to each one. At least, that's what I want to do, but the `client.HTTPConnection` doesn't seem to.

Internally, client.HTTPConnection eventually calls `socket.create_connection`, but I've traced the code and can't figure out a good work-around.

I've tried URL's like `http://2899902734:80/` for Google as well as `http://172.217.1.14` and they don't work.

Comment: two questions:  1. Are you just checking for the existance of a file? and 2. you know that a file exists on `172.217.1.14`?  Thx

Comment: I'm collecting the HTTP headers, but not the body. I'm sending a HEAD command.

Comment: maybe you could do it more of a rest pattern using urlib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347888/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-on-http-exists-using-python-django