# urllib2.urlopen - close faster when given a wrong link

Tags: python, urllib2

I want my program to try to open the page and get the data in time interval *[0,t]*, if that time expires connection should be close. 
I'm using *urllib2* to try to accomplish the task.

```
t=1
url="http://example.com"
response=urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=t)
html=response.read()
```

This seems to work if url exists. However, if you put some nonexistent url it takes too long for error to stop the program. And if I put this program to be used by some web site the user would need to wait for error message for too long. 
Is there a way to stop execution of *urlopen* command if it takes longer than set time?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just checking if the link is correct, [use a HEAD request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python/2070916#2070916).

Comment: No, I want it to stop in less than 1 second if the link is wrong. Try putting the wrong link into code that you've linked to, you'll have to wait for 20 seconds before you get an error msg.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're experiencing such long delays.

When I try and make a request to a non-existant domain, I get `urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>` raised in about `0.2` seconds.

What's the exact code you're running and domain you're fetching?

<s>Try using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and the timeout parameter.</s>

Comment: "What's the exact code you're running and domain you're fetching?"

Comment: line1: url="http://jdoiajoisdzzzzzej.com" line2: response=urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=1) , under Linux python 2.7.2+

Comment: I did that too, the same result. I have to wait for error for a long time.