# urllib doesn't give me correct filetype

Tags: python, image, url, urllib

I'm using the urllib python module to get images from an external URL.
It works well, but there are some images that give me problems like this:
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/2014/01/grunt-logo-400.png

My code is the following

```
import urllib
img = urllib.urlretrieve("https://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/2014/01/grunt-logo-400.png")
```

When I print img it show me:
"/tmp/tmpbuhfUW.png"

But if I print img[1].type it gives me:
"text/html"

So the filetype is incorrect.

Is there anny solution?

PS: I checked my /tmp folder where the image is downloaded and I noticed the image is blank.
PS2: also I've tried with urllib2.urlopen("cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/2014/01/grunt-logo-400.png") But it gives me error 403

UPDATE:
Finally I solved it by doing the following:

```
class MyOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'

myopener = MyOpener()
i = myopener.retrieve("https://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/2014/01/grunt-logo-400.png")
```

Now it prints the filetype as "image/png"

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389090/how-to-use-urllib-to-download-image-from-web

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you aren't doing anything wrong. Urllib is just guessing the mime type incorrectly. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but you could say

```
filetype = img[0].split('.')[1]
```

to retrieve the filetype, and then check if it was contained in an array of different image filetypes to determine if it was a link to an image.

Comment: I checked my /tmp folder where the image is downloaded and I noticed the image is blank.

Comment: Does that happen with every image that isn't recognized correctly?

Comment: Also I've tried with urllib2.urlopen("https://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/2014/01/grunt-logo-400.png") But it gives me error 403

Comment: yes. Most of images work correctly, but some images give me a different filetype

Comment: Well, error 403 is an error that you get when you aren't allowed to access a file within a website. Usually you get this error when you're trying to get to places in a website directly from the url (which is basically what you're doing). They do this to stop people from accessing files or directories which they shouldn't be, so they probably just don't want you to access the image which you're trying to download. I might just leave it alone.

Comment: But, Why can I access to the image from the browser without problems but not from urllib?

Comment: I found this: "Some websites will block access from scripts to avoid 'unnecessary' usage of their servers by reading the headers urllib sends. I don't know and can't imagine why wikipedia does/would do this, but have you tried spoofing your headers?"