# Entering the url in the browser, downloads the image automatically. How to write a python script to download such images?

Tags: python, image, urllib

url="https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2016/02/96128cfd-ab9a-4959-972e-a5e74bb149a9.jpg"

I am trying this:
import urllib 
url="https://images.data.gov.sg/api/traffic-images/2016/02/96128cfd-ab9a-4959-972e-a5e74bb149a9.jpg" 
IMAGE=url.rsplit("/")[-1] 
urllib.urlretrieve(url,IMAGE)

**Image is downloaded in the destination folder after the execution, but it is corrupt. 
"Could not load image"; error pops up.**

Comment: This is probably, because the url is _not_ an image, it causes (in a browser) a new request which finally gets the image. I'm not sure if `urllib` automatically follows redirects. Have a look at http://python-requests.org - I've found this library better documented and easier to use.

Comment: Thanks!  The requests module worked

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the domain that you are trying to reach has restrictions over download policy. Check this one out, hope it helps! https://stackoverflow.com/a/8389368/2539771

Answer (score 0):

import urllib
URL = "[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/714tx9QbaKL.*SL1500*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/714tx9QbaKL._SL1500_.jpg)"
urllib.urlretrieve(URL, "sample.png")

from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('/home/sks/sample.png')
img.show()