# Possible to do Appengine urlfetch or urllib2 HEAD request?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urllib2, urlfetch

Hello Stack Overflow!

I understand that Python's urllib2 library can perform HEAD requests: [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python)

Does this mean if I want to do a HEAD request, I need to use urllib2? Also, can urlli2 on appengine do a HEAD request (suspicious because it doesn't appear that urlfetch can https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction)

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. urllib2 can't do anything urlfetch can't.
"When running in App Engine, these libraries perform HTTP requests using App Engine's URL fetch service, which runs on Google's scalable HTTP request infrastructure."

BUT! "The URL fetch service supports five HTTP methods: GET, POST, HEAD, PUT and DELETE."

Just didn't see it in the urlfetch reference documentation.

- source: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview