# Python check status of URL stream

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python to check if a MJPEG stream url is alive or not.

I've tried the following:

```
 connection = urlopen('http://localhost/videostream.cgi'), timeout=10)
 response = connection.getcode()
 connection.close()
```

With no luck, it just times out of gives an error.

If I view the status in a firebug or chrome dev toolbar, the status is always "Pending" instead of "200".

Is there a way to check to make sure it's not a 404 or other error?

Cheers,
Ben

Comment: You could send a HEAD request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python

Comment: hmm for some reason that throws a "Connection reset by peer" error. Could it have something to do with the site requiring Basic Auth?

Comment: turns out it was my camera web server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was my camera web server.