# How to get the length of a mp3 link in python?

Tags: python, mp3

I need get a mp3 lenght(from a url) to transform the lenght in seconds for a delay, someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of retrieving the resource (mp3 file), and printing the track length via [mutagen](https://code.google.com/p/mutagen/) library:

```
from urllib import urlretrieve

from mutagen.mp3 import MP3


url = 'http://example.com/foo.mp3'
filename, headers = urlretrieve(url)

audio = MP3(filename)
print audio.info.length
```

Comment: I tried to find the mutagen.mp3 module, and i not found it.

Comment: pip install mutagen (for python 2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to retrieve he resource, you can just check the headers as here:
[How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python) You want to call the HEAD method which gets you the file size without downloading the file:

Comment: the OP wants song length, not file size.  afaik, you must have the track locally to get that.