# url_rewrite_access mimetype filtering not working

Tags: acl, squid

I have a `squid.config` file that routes requests to a redirector. I only really want `text/html` mime types to be passed to it. Here's the configurations that I have to do that:

```
url_rewrite_program /usr/bin/python3 /etc/squid3/custom_redirect.py

#only allow text/html mime types
acl html_only req_mime_type -i ^text/html$
url_rewrite_access allow html_only

#deny all other requests
url_rewrite_access deny all
```

When I call a website, I see that the `access.log` shows that I've made request with a `text/html` mime type, but none of them go through the redirect. I've looked around, but no one seems to have the same problem and the documentation makes it seem I'm in the right. Any thoughts as to why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR: Check MIME type from within the `url_rewrite_program`*

I have assumed (based on what most people would probably be wanting) that what you are trying to achieve is filtering of **reply** MIME types, that is the MIME type of the file on the server.

You would in theory need to change `req_mime_type` to `rep_mime_type` however continue reading before bothering.

This is the result of the timing of various events during Squid's processing of the HTTP request.

Immediately after receiving the request from the client Squid evaluates the acls associated with `url_rewrite_access` then if needed then `url_rewrite_program` is run. The problem is at this point Squid does has not sent, and therefore has not received, anything to/from the server, it therefore has no way of accurately evaluating the `rep_mime_type`

My solution to this was to evaluate the MIME type using the script itself.

I used PHP but for Python take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107405/4110980).