# How to get content-type from selenium page_source

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, content-type

I know the content-type can be gotten from

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content-type = response.info().getheader('Content-type')
```

Now, I need to execute js code so I choose selenium with Phantomjs to fetch web page.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
source = driver.page_source
```

How can I get content-type from source without downloading web page twice? I know I can save the response.read() as html file, and then driver render the local html file without downloading it again. However, it's too slow. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selenium does not get the headers but you can just request the head with requests:

```
import  requests

print(requests.head(url).headers["Content-Type"])
```

You can use httplib2, urliib2 etc.. there are numerous [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python) showing how to request the head with various libs.

Comment: Thx! it really helps.

Comment: No worries,  a head request should be pretty efficient.