# How do you send a HEAD HTTP request with Tornado?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado

I'm a newbie to [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) and I'm trying to use it to make an async HEAD HTTP request. How is that done with Tornado?

My question is inspired by this one: [How do you send a HEAD HTTP request in Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107405/how-do-you-send-a-head-http-request-in-python-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `method="HEAD"` to your `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch()` call.

```
response = await http_client.fetch("http://example.com", method="HEAD")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.5+:

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

async def fetch_head():
    response = await http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    print(response.headers)
    IOLoop.current().stop()

http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
IOLoop.current().add_callback(fetch_head)
IOLoop.current().start()
```

In real code, don't call "stop" until all processing is complete and your program is ready to exit.

In older Python replace async / await with gen.coroutine and yield:

```
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def fetch_head():
    response = yield http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/")
    print(response.headers)
    IOLoop.current().stop()
```

Comment: What if I want to do this every second again and again? Each time a different URL? This is for a crawling application that brute force checks to see if pages exist.

Comment: Follow the example for [Running in the background](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/guide/coroutines.html#running-in-the-background). You want to fetch the URL within a try/catch block, do something if there's an exception, and then sleep for a second and loop.